# Showing there are no "alternate" natural numbers

Tags: real-analysis

I've been self-studying real analysis from Tao's Analysis 1 and have run into the following problem which I am having difficulty with.

> *Exercise* 3.5.13. The purpose of this exercise is to show that there is essentially only one version of the natural number system in set theory (cf. the discussion in Remark 2.1.12). Suppose we have a set $\mathbb{N}'$ of "alternative natural numbers", an "alternate zero" $0'$, and an "alternate increment operation" which takes any alternate natural number $n'\in\mathbb{N}'$ and returns another alternative natural number $n'++'\in\mathbb{N}'$, such that the Peano Axioms (Axioms 2.1-2.5) all hold with the natural numbers, zero, and increment replaced by their alternative counterparts. Show that there exists a bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}'$ from the natural numbers to the alternative natural numbers such that $f(0)=0'$, and such that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n'\in\mathbb{N}'$, we have $f(n)=n'$ if and only if $f(n++)=n'++'$. (Hint: use Exercise 3.5.12.)

To solve this, I define the function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}'$ as $$f=\begin{cases} f(0)=0' \\ f(n++)=f(n)++'. \end{cases}$$ Now, we can show injectivity and surjectivity of $f$ using induction on either $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{N}'$.

Edit: I have been able to solve it with some help, and have edited my answer to reflect the new function I'm using.

Comment: Use the induction principle in $\mathbb N'$ to show that each element is in the range of $f$. (That's after you repair the definition of $f$; as it stands, $g(f(n))$ doesn't make sense because $g$ is defined on $\mathbb N$ while $f(n)$ is in $\mathbb N'$.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass Isn't $g$ a function from $\mathbb{N}'\to\mathbb{N}'$, as $f(n)\in\mathbb{N}'$ and $(\mathbb{N}')++'\in\mathbb{N}'$? Also, how would I go about fixing my definition of $f$?

Comment: You defined $g$ by $g(n)=(f(n))++$, which presupposes that $f(n)$ is defined. And $f(n)$ is defined for $n$ in $\mathbb N$, not $\mathbb N'$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Their definition of $g$ is using the operation $++'$, not $++$.

Comment: Hm so I've thought of a new way of defining $f$ as follows: $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}'$ is defined as: $f(0):=0'$ and $f(n++):=n'++'$ if $f(n)=n'$ and $n\neq0,n\in\mathbb{N}$. Although this definition doesn't seem very recursive to me, it seems to get the job done. I can show that $f$ is injective in similar fashion to my original post, and I can also now show that $f$ is surjective in a similar fashion. Hence, I can conclude that there is a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}'$, allowing me to conclude that there is only one distinct system of naturals that obey the Peano Axioms.

Comment: A simple $f(n\text{++}) := f(n)\text{++}'$ will do Both of your definitions are just saying the same thing in a more convoluted form (and it is definitely recursive in any version, as $f(n)$ must be defined before $f(n\text{++})$ can be). (And speaking as someone who does a lot of programming in C-like languages and uses the `++` operator frequently, I still find the traditional $s(n)$ notation much more preferable for mathematics.)

Comment: @conditionalMethod Thanks for pointing out the typo in my previous comment. Fortunately, it doesn't affect the main point of the comment, namely that the definition of $g(n)$ presupposes that $f(n)$ is defined, so $n$ has to be in $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass No, none of your comment made any sense.